# Refreshing A Tab Bar after changing UIAppearence

Tags: ios, ios5, uiappearance

I have an idea that I would like to try to implement:

Basically, I want to be able to make it easy to distinguish between being logged in and not being logged in my application.  My idea is that, when the user is not logged in, the app will set background color, etc. in an UIAppearence proxy.  After they log in, these values will be changed by altering the UIAppearence settings.

I have found that this sort of works, but not all of the UI elements will be refreshed after changing UIAppearence.  The most prominent example is the tab bar in my UITabBarController (which is the rootViewController of my window).

In searching for the solution to this problem, I have found some suggestions that `layoutSubviews` or `drawRect` needs to be called in order for the view to refresh and adopt the changes to UIAppearence.  I have tried all of the following without success, however, in my app delegate:

```
[self.window.rootViewController.view setNeedsLayout]
[self.window.rootViewController.view setNeedsDisplay]

[self.tabbarController.tabBar setNeedsLayout]
[self.tabbarController.tabBar setNeedsDisplay]

[self.tabbarController.view setNeedsLayout]
[self.tabbarController.view setNeedsDisplay]
```

Anyone have any tricks or insights into how I might force the tab bar (and other views) to be redrawn?  I am thinking that I just want to send calls to `layoutSubviews` all the way down the UIView hierarchy but, if so, I haven't found a way to do that yet.

Answer (score 3):

UIAppearance properties are set after view is added to views hierarchy.
The easiest trick to trigger it again is to detach key window's rootViewController and then attach it again. You can also remove key window's subviews and add them again.

Answer (score 1):

I have used KVO to notify my custom UITabBar.

My trick was:

1. create UITabBar subclass
2. Link it to UITabBarController on XIB/StoryBoard
3. Add Observer on item creation (override - (void)setItems:(NSArray *)items animated:(BOOL)animate)
4. Handle observer

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I am looking for something specific to UIAppearance, however.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet that I use to refresh my application's UIAppearance after changing internal theme.

```
NSArray *windows = [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows;
for (UIWindow *window in windows) {
    for (UIView *view in window.subviews) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
        [window addSubview:view];
    }
}
```

http://snipplr.com/view/75259/refresh-uiappearance-after-application-loaded/

Hope it'll work for your needs, for me it's perfect.

Comment: Hi David , I have tried it but it didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

It`s been a long time since you asked this problem.
I have faced a same problem when I tried to apply dark mode(iOS13).

UITabbar has been modified with 'appearance API' and when the mode has been changed, but nothing changed. I have to force change text color and font.

My solution is following.

1. Implement 'traitCollectionDidChange' API on the subclass of UIViewController.
2. Iterate items of UITabbar
3. setTitleAttributes with 'setTitleTextAttributes' of UITabbarItem

thanks.

Comment: I have met the same problem. I set the item's selected image for dark mode. When I switch mode in 'Settings'. It doesn't change. So I think it should be a bug in iOS 13.0.